# UPPAAL: Do clocks given as function parameters have methods or attributes?

Tags: uppaal

I'm currently using UPPAAL v.4.1.19 and have seen in the help that clocks can be given as function parameters. However i couldn't find any information about what methods or attributes, eg. lower and upper bounds of the clock, are available for the clocks.

Example function:

```
void access_clock(clock & cl){
    //access clock here
}
```

Is it possible to get the lower bound of the clock or doing something else with it in a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

The timed automata model allows only clock comparisons (in guards) and assignments (in updates). Functions with clock arguments may only assign the clock variables.
The lower and upper bounds are the result of model-checking (symbolic analysis), are outside the model and thus do not belong to the model itself.

The clock variable is said to have positive real value which increases together with time -- that is all to it, and this expressiveness is intentionally limited so that the analysis would still be decidable.